# Require unique value from two different worksheet

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

Could you please help me to get output for considering two worksheets (Emp Salary- Nov-22.CSV / Emp Salary- Dec-22.CSV). I want to get each column's unique name value in new output file.

Comment: Hello, Rakesh. Welcome to stackoverflow. It is hard to answer your question because it is not exactly clear what is the input and the desired output. please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I just need to create a output file that includes both sheet unique value in each column and duplicates data/ Value should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in Excel with pivot tables.
But if you are looking for a apandas method... I have created 2 dataframes like you have

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
      { "Name": ['Govind', 'Chetan', 'Rahul'],
        "City": ['Mumbai', 'Banglore', 'Pune'],
        "Salary": [1, 1, 1] })

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
      { "Name": ['Govind', 'Chetan', 'Kalpesh'],
        "City": ['Mumbai', 'Banglore', 'Pune'],
        "Salary": [1, 1, 1] })
```

You can then use concat to concatenate them

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
df
```

[image: concat]

and you can use groupby() and reset_index() to get what you want

```
df.groupby(['Name','City'])['Salary'].sum().reset_index()
```

[image: grouped]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) with `sheet_name=None` to read all the sheets at once and then pass the dictionnary of dataframes made to [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and finally use [`Groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) for aggregation :

```
import pandas as pd

out = (
         pd.concat(pd.read_excel("/input_spreadsheet.xlsx", sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)
              .groupby(["Name", "City"], as_index=False)["Salary"].sum()
      )
```

After that, if needed, you can make an new spreadsheet with [`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) and/or a (`.csv`) file with [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) :

```
out.to_excel("/output_spreadsheet.xlsx", sheet_name="Emp Salary (Total).xlsx", index=False)
out.to_csv("/output_csvfile.csv", sheet_name="Emp Salary (Total).csv", sep=",", index=False) #sep="," by default
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

        Name       City  Salary
0     Chetan  Bangalore   60000
1     Dipesh       Pune   50000
2     Govind     Mumbai  200000
3    Kalpesh    Kolkata   40000
4      Rahul    Kolkata   40000
5    Santosh       Pune   50000
6  Siddharth  Hyderabad   50000
```

Comment: no need to sum the salary, I just need to create a output file that includes both sheet unique value in each column and duplicates data/ Value should be removed.

Comment: This is not what shows your _image/output_.